# Optuna: ValueError: No trials are completed yet. Trial 0 failed with value None

Tags: python, valueerror, autoencoder, hyperparameters, optuna

I want to optimize with optuna the hyperparameters for my convolutional autoencoder but i keep getting this error that no trials are completed. Any ideas?

[W 2023-04-22 17:57:07,202] Trial 0 failed with parameters: {'learning_rate': 0.0001, 'weight': 1e-06, 'drop': 0.8, 'conv1': 128, 'conv2': 8, 'conv3': 128, 'fc': 130, 'latent_dim': 100} because of the following error: The value None could not be cast to float..

[W 2023-04-22 17:57:07,228] Trial 0 failed with value None.

ValueError: No trials are completed yet.

This is the code:
`

```
class Encoder_cae1_hp(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hyperparameters=dict):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        
                   nn.Conv1d(1,hyperparameters['conv1'],5, stride=3),
                   nn.Dropout(hyperparameters['drop']),

                   nn.Conv1d(hyperparameters['conv1'], hyperparameters['conv2'], 3, stride=3),
                   nn.LeakyReLU(),
        
                   
                   nn.Conv1d(hyperparameters['conv2'], hyperparameters['conv3'], 4, stride=2),
                   nn.Dropout(hyperparameters['drop']),
                   nn.LeakyReLU(),
        
               
                   nn.Flatten(start_dim=1),
        
                   nn.Linear(2924*hyperparameters['conv3'], hyperparameters['fc']),
        
                   nn.Linear(hyperparameters['fc'], hyperparameters['latent_dim']))
                
    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.encoder(x)
        return z



class Decoder_cae1_hp(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hyperparameters=dict):
        super().__init__()

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hyperparameters['latent_dim'], hyperparameters['fc']),
            nn.Linear(hyperparameters['fc'], 2924*hyperparameters['conv3']),
           
            nn.Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(hyperparameters['conv3'], 2924)),
        
        
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(hyperparameters['conv3'], hyperparameters['conv2'], 4, stride=2,output_padding=1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(hyperparameters['drop']),
        
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(hyperparameters['conv2'], hyperparameters['conv1'], 3, stride=3, padding =0, output_padding=2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(hyperparameters['drop']),
            
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(hyperparameters['conv1'], 1, 5, stride=3, padding =0, output_padding=1)
           
            )
                    
    def forward(self, x):
        reconstruction = self.decoder(x)
        return reconstruction

#%% Hyperparameters
def objective(trial: optuna.trial.Trial) -> float:
    
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_categorical("learning_rate", [1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3])
    weight = trial.suggest_categorical("weight", [1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-6])
    
    drop = trial.suggest_float("drop", 0.0, 1, step = 0.2)

    conv1 =  trial.suggest_categorical("conv1", [8, 16, 32, 64, 128])
    conv2 =  trial.suggest_categorical("conv2", [8, 16, 32, 64, 128])
    conv3 =  trial.suggest_categorical("conv3", [8, 16, 32, 64, 128])
    
    fc = trial.suggest_categorical("fc", [30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 270, 320])


    latent_dim = trial.suggest_categorical("latent_dim", [20,40,60,80,100])
    train_batch = trial.suggest_categorical("train_batch", [10,20,40,60,80,100])
    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

    hyperparameters = {
        'learning_rate': learning_rate, 
        'drop':drop,
        'conv1':conv1, 
        'conv2':conv2,
        'conv3':conv3,
        'fc':fc,
        'weight':weight,
        'latent_dim':latent_dim
        }


#%% 
    data = dataset.linearized_matrices()

    encoder = Encoder_cae1_hp(hyperparameters = hyperparameters) 
    decoder = Decoder_cae1_hp(hyperparameters = hyperparameters) 
    
#%% Train the optimizer   
    train_points, val_points = train_test_split(data, test_size= 0.1, shuffle=True, random_state = 0)

    train_points = dataset.Dataset(train_points, transform = dataset.ToTensor())
    validation_points = dataset.Dataset(val_points, transform = dataset.ToTensor())

    train_points_dl= DataLoader(train_points, batch_size = train_batch, shuffle= True)
    validation_points_dl= DataLoader(validation_points, batch_size = len(validation_points), shuffle=False)

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([{'params': encoder.parameters()},{'params': decoder.parameters()}], lr = hyperparameters['learning_rate'], weight_decay = hyperparameters['weight'])

    device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
    print(f'Selected device: {device}')
            
    encoder.to(device)
    decoder.to(device)
            
    try:
        num_epochs = 30
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                print(f'################# \n | EPOCH {epoch+1} | \n')
                train_loss = train.train(encoder, decoder, device, train_points_dl, loss_fn, optimizer)
                print(f'\t Average train loss for epoch: {train_loss.data}')
                val_loss, _ = test.test(encoder, decoder, device, validation_points_dl, loss_fn)
                print('\n\t VALIDATION - EPOCH %d/%d - loss: %f\n' % (epoch + 1, num_epochs, val_loss))            
                
                if trial.should_prune():
                     raise optuna.exceptions.TrialPruned()
                trial.report(val_loss)
        return val_loss         
        
    except RuntimeError:
       trial.set_user_attr("constraint", (1,)) 
        
        

def print_best_callback(study, trial):
    print(f"Best value: {study.best_value}, Best params: {study.best_trial.params}")


#%%
study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials = 800, gc_after_trial = True, callbacks=[print_best_callback])


And the test function that returns the val_loss:

def test(encoder, decoder, device, dataloader, loss_fn):
    encoder.eval()
    decoder.eval()
    latent_codes = dict(z = [], subj_id = [])
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        for subj, image_batch in dataloader:  

            image_batch = image_batch.to(device)
            z = encoder(image_batch)             
            reconstruction = decoder(z)         
            latent_codes['z'].append(z.detach().cpu())            
            latent_codes['subj_id'].append(subj) 
            val_loss = loss_fn(reconstruction, image_batch)
    return val_loss.data, latent_codes
```

`